# Requirements for subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading these two sections of text:

[image]

and

[image]

Why is there an emphasis on nonempty? Isn't that by definition always true? According to these two pieces of text, a subspace needs to be:

- be closed under addition
- be closed under multiplicaiton
- have a zero vector.

I can see why 6b in this following text is not a subspace... it does not contain the zero vector. But according to 4.5, it's a subspace because it satisfies the two points and is nonempty right? Something seems inconsistent to me here. According to 4.5, the set of points in 6b is a subspace right?

[image]

Comment: The empty set does not have the zero vector as an element.

Comment: Are you saying that $2x+y = 1$ is cloesd under multiplication? Think again. Closed under addition? Think again, again. You are saying that if $2x+y = 1$ then $2cx + cy = 1$ for all scalars $c$. Is this true?

Comment: The line $2x+y-1=0$ provides an affine subspace but not a linear subspace (zero vector).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the statement of Theorem 4.5 without the assumption that $W$ be non-empty.  If $W=\varnothing$, then $W$ satisfies conditions $1.$ and $2.$ of the theorem (vacuously, of course). So if we don't specify that $W$ is nonempty, then the theorem would say that the empty set is a subspace of $V$, which is false.  Thus we need to specify that $W$ is non-empty.

The set of points in $\mathbb R^2$ satisfying $x+2y=1$ is not a subspace, for many reasons.  Pick any two points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ such that $x_1+2y_1=1$ and $x_2+2y_2=1$.  Then 
$$(x_1+x_2)+2(y_1+y_2)=(x_1+2y_1)+(x_2+2y_2)=1+1\neq 1,$$
 so $(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)$ does not satisfy the given equation.  Hence this set is not closed under addition, and therefore it is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The set of points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ that satisfy $x+2y=1$ is not a vector space according to Theorem $4.5$. Notice that $(1,0)$ is a solution but $2 (1,0)=(2,0)$ is not, so it is not closed under scalar multiplication.

It follows from Theorem $4.5$ that every vector subspace must contain the zero vector because for every vector $x$ it holds that $x+(-1)x=0$.